# select query with date in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I want to select records from date with a specific date. The problem is there is timestamp in the date. For example:

```
Table name : books
record 1 : 09-04-2018 10:31:00
record 2 : 09-04-2018 10:32:00
record 3 : 09-04-2018 10:33:00
record 4 : 10-04-2018 17:54:00
record 5 : 10-04-2018 18:49:01
```

I want to retrieve all records on date 09-04-2018 irrespective of the time.

`select * from books where bookdate >= '09-04-2018'` => This query is returning me all 5 records instead of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is column/literal datatype:

```
select * from books where date::date >= '2018-04-09'::date;
```

> " I try your query, still it returns all 5!"

Well, `2018-04-09 00:00:00` is smaller than all your 5 values.

Comment: the datatype is timestamp. I try your query, still it returns all 5!!